# SSRS Calculate total body length of a report before sent it to printer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using SSRS to print some receipt tickets, I don't know hw many items would be on that ticket until it is finished at production time, could be one or could be one hundred or even more. I need to print it in a roll paper instead of pages.

SSRS doesn't allow it directly, then  I need to set up page Height size at run time according the amount of items to print.

There is any way to calculate/get the body size of my report, before print it?

NOTE: Header and footer has a predefined length.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What do you mean by print it without page breaks?  And what are you referring to as the page length?  It would help if you use the same terminology that is provided in the dialogs used to adjust the settings you're looking for.

Comment: @WesH I changed some terms and try to explain it better.

Comment: SSRS is a paginated report renderer.  I'm 99% sure it does not support roll printing.  The page height is not dynamically adjustable.

Comment: I agree with Wes. The only time you can do this is by setting the interactive page size to 0 but that only works on the HTML renderer, printed reports always have to have the page size specified and you cannot change it dynamically.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Tks :(